# How to return a list with brackets?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code and its giving me a list as output without brackets 
example `4,3,2,1`, where I wanted to return `[4,3,2,1]`.

Please let me know where my small mistake is.

```
def inverse(mdg):
    i = 0
    Sr = ''
    while i < len(mdg):
        Sr =Sr + mdg[-(i+1)]
        i = i+1
    return Sr
ch = (input('Veuillez entrer une liste des valeurs separees par virgules: '))
l1 = list(ch.split(','))
print((",".join(inverse(l1))))
```

Comment: Is your real problem to make it print that way (if yes, just add '[' before and  ']' after), or is it to actually build a list of numbers (not characters) and then display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is about return string like '[4,3,2,1]', not list.
Also it need to remove " of elements.

Code

```
def inverse(mdg):
    """This function reversed string without quotemark of reversed list of splitted input by ','
    """
    return ",".join(reversed(mdg.split(','))).join(["[", "]"])
```

Sample

```
>>> ch = (input('Veuillez entrer une liste des valeurs separees par virgules: '))
Veuillez entrer une liste des valeurs separees par virgules: 1,2,3,4
>>> inverse(ch)
'[4,3,2,1]'
>>> print(inverse(ch))
[4,3,2,1]
```

Or just add '.join(["[", "]"])

```
def inverse(mdg):
    i = 0
    Sr = ''
    while i < len(mdg):
        Sr =Sr + mdg[-(i+1)]
        i = i+1
    return Sr
ch = (input('Veuillez entrer une liste des valeurs separees par virgules: '))
l1 = list(ch.split(','))
print((",".join(inverse(l1)).join(['[',']'])))
```

Comment: There are chances that the OP requires a actual list instead of string :)

Comment: @VigneshKalai, If just want to inverse the list, 'list(reversed(input_list))' is enough.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are returning a string not a list

If that's what you want the just add `[` to beginning and `]` to the end of the string like this

**Modification:**

```
def inverse(mdg):
    i = 0
    Sr = ''
    while i < len(mdg):
        Sr =Sr + mdg[-(i+1)]
        i = i+1
    return Sr
ch = (input('Veuillez entrer une liste des valeurs separees par virgules: '))
l1 = list(ch.split(','))
print("["+",".join(inverse(l1))+"]")
```

Try adding to `list` instead of `string` to return  a list

**Code:**

```
def inverse(mdg):
    i = 0
    Sr = []  # Create list
    while i < len(mdg):
        Sr  += mdg[-(i+1)] # Add to list
        i = i+1
    return Sr  # Return list 
ch = input('Veuillez entrer une liste des valeurs separees par virgules: ')
l1 = ch.split(',')
print(inverse(l1))
```

**Output:**

```
Veuillez entrer une liste des valeurs separees par virgules: 1,2,3,4
['4', '3', '2', '1']
```

There is no need to create a function to reverse a list it can be done as simple as this

**Code2:**

```
ch = input('Veuillez entrer une liste des valeurs separees par virgules: ')
l1 = ch.split(',')
print(l1[::-1]) # Reverses the list
```

The output is a list of string if you want a list of numbers

use this snippet before printing

**snippet:**

```
print (map(int,listofstrings)) # Prints list of numbers
```

Comment: `.split()` return a list so you don't need call `list()` function again.

Comment: @KevinGuan yes thanks .The morning coffee did not work :P

Comment: This question want to return '[4, 3, 2, 1]', not '['4', '3', '2', '1']'.

Comment: If thats the case a simple map function can do it @EveryEvery